# Help My World Got Deleted!

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister and I were playing minecraft PE and it was on my iPhone C that the world was on and suddenly I disconnected and only the base of the building we created was there. We are very upset because of the time and effort lost. Why did this happen and is there any way to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

If you have iCloud backup enabled restoring a backup will restore it.